# Retrieving the unreadCount tag for a YouTube video

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, google-data-api

How do I get the `unreadCount` value using the YouTube client library?

I think this is a new tag in the YouTube Data API, but I can't find the API method to get it.
I can only get some values through SubscriptionEntry:

```
SubscriptionFeed feed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), SubscriptionFeed.class);

for(SubscriptionEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    System.out.println("Feed Url: " + entry.getFeedUrl());
    System.out.println("CountHint: " + entry.getCountHint());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking is ["contentDetails.newItemCount"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#contentDetails.newItemCount)

You can het it via [getContentDetails().getNewItemCount()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/SubscriptionContentDetails.html#getNewItemCount%28%29)

Comment: Thank you! But this is for Data API v3? Does any function can be used in YouTube Data API v2?

Comment: Yes, this is for v3, v2 is not actively supported anymore. I'd definitely suggest you to switch to v3 sooner than later.